# fix broken xml with wild < > signs

Tags: xml, python-2.7

A piece of software gives me bad xml with stuff like this :

```
<sometag> some textnode with < and > characters in the middle of it</sometag>
So you can potentially have <notatag> but <isatag>some text</isatag>
```

So when I try to put this into minidom's xml parser it's quite understandably not happy.

My goal is to translate the < > characters into their appropriate escape sequence :

```
<sometag> some textnode with &lt; and &gt; characters in the middle of it</sometag>
So you can potentially have &lt;notatag&gt; but <isatag>some text</isatag>
```

I saw lxml's parser recover option (http://lxml.de/parsing.html) but it tries to complete and close stuff that looks like tag, or delete wild < > characters. I want to keep the text exactly the same, with everything that cannot be a valid tag converted to escape characters.

- I don't have a complete list of possible tags
- But it can only contain alphanumeric characters. no attributes, no weird stuff.
- You can have nested tags
- I currently process the file line by line to do other stuff before I run the parser, to put the fix here would save me time and would be appreciated. You can't have a pair of tags split into two lines.

Thanks for your time and your kind help.

Comment: I think you're either looking at writing a custom XML parser or getting a full list of tags.  You can't really treat this document as XML, and by the time you made it conform to XML you'd be most of the way to completely parsing it yourself.

Comment: @DanField I hoped I had missed something but yes the task is not trivial :/ The workaround is to replace every < > before running the software, which means a complete read/write of every file and quite a time lost. Damn.